# Why doesn't this jQuery code work in IE?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This works in all browsers except IE. I have no idea why. Its just an ajax clock that ticks through the seconds.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Time Program Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
   zone = 'Africa/Djibouti';
   ajaxTimeCall(zone, ajaxCallback);
         });
function ajaxTimeCall(zone, callback) {
$.ajax({
     type: 'get',
     url: 'time.php',
     context: this,
     data: 'location=' + zone,
     success: function (data){
     var dataSplit = data.split(".");
     var isDST = dataSplit[1];
     var newTime = new Date(dataSplit[0]);
     //console.log(newTime);
     if(isNaN(newTime))
      {
      $('#clock_input').val("Timezone Not Recognized");
      return;
      }
     $('#clock_input').val(newTime);
     callback(isDST);
     }

  }); 
}
function ajaxCallback(isDST) {

  setTimeout("ajaxTimeCall(zone, ajaxCallback)", 1000);
  if (isDST == 1)
   $('.DST').removeClass('noshow');
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.noshow { display: none;}
.DST {color: red; font-size: 14px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1> World Time Ajax Testing</h1>
<span class="DST noshow">(DST)</span>
<form name="test" action="">
<input id="clock_input" style="width: 175px; font-size: 14px;" type="text" value="Turn on Javascript" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your problem is in your question: it's "in IE"

Comment: Coult you specify "doesn't work"? What happens, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Comment: How does it "not work"? jQuery doesn't work completely in IE, but it deprecates relatively cleanly usually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you've already solved this with a `POST`, but there is another way as well, use [the `cache` option for `$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  By setting it to `false`, jquery will append a timestamp to the URL as a parameter, forcing a new request even in IE, you use it like this:

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  //current options you already have...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your code be:

```
ajaxCallback(isDST);
```

in your ajax success callback in the function `ajaxTimeCall`?

If you could provide more details about the error that you're seeing, that would also help.

Comment: Sorry about that I guess it would be helpful to know what I'm seeing. It displays an incorrect time in an incorrect format in IE. The correct time can be seen if you view it in FF or Chrome or Safari. It seems like its getting a different value for data back from the server than the other browsers. I have no idea why the format is different though.

Also I think the callback name is correct since I pass the ajaxCallback() function into that callback name when I call ajaxTimeCall in the document.ready section? Is that incorrect?